# Cant connect to local teradata database in VMware image

Tags: errors, teradata

Login credentials for VM

```
linux: root/root
database: dbc/dbc
```

The image`ve been downloaded from [here](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/database). (this version TDExpress15.00.02.08_Sles11_40GB.7z)

I successfully launched VM image, but failed to connect to database. I started Teradata studio and entered dbc/dbc  as login/pass – and he couldn’t connect(ping problems).

How can I check the existence of teradata? What am I doing wrong? Is where any user guide?

**UPD1**  I`m trying to connect within the VM. Result of next command:

> pdestate -a

```
pde state is RUN/STARTED.
DBS state is 0/-1: DBS is not running
```

I tried such command, but I think it doesn't work properly:

> /etc/init.d/tpa start

PDE (PdeMain) already running: use 'tparest -f force'

> tparest -f force

```
you are about to restart the database on the system 'SLES11SP1'
do u wish to continue?
```

So I pressed `Y`, then I repeated this steps several times, so DBS state changed to 5. And I connected successfully))

Comment: Did you specify the correct ip-adress of the Teradata VM? Use the one returned by `ifconfig ethic`. If you run Studio from within the VM you can use `localhost`. If it's still not working, check if Teradata is started running `pdestate -a` on command line

Comment: "DBS is not running" is bad, try `/etc/init.d/tpa start` and repeat the `pdestate -a` several times, if it still fails "/var/log/messages" will have more info why.

Comment: Thank you a lot @dnoeth - database launched, but `ifconfig ethic` returned error, that `device not found`

Comment: @dnoeth `ifconfig -a` returned 2 device eth0(192.168.***.***) and lo (127.0.0.1)

Comment: Sorry for the `ethic`, should be `eth0`, damn autocorrection :-)  Within the VM use `localhost` and the ip-address from outside.